# Refrescar página en loop

Tags: javascript, bucles

Lo primero disculpas porque soy totalmente novato en javascript.

Quiero hacer un loop infinito, en el cual, mediante un prompt, le pida al usuario un dato y lo ponga en pantalla. El problema lo tengo en que, mientras se está ejecutando el loop con el prompt, la pantalla no se refresca.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h2>Bucle infinito compra papeleria</h2>
<h3>Stock</h3>
<p id="tablePrint"></p>
<script>
let compraManolo;

do {  
document.getElementById('tablePrint').innerHTML = compraManolo;
compraManolo = prompt("Lápices?");
}
while (compraManolo < 10);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿que quieres decir con que no se refresca?  en tu snippet yo veo que si aparece el valor puesto cada vez que lo ejecutas y te pide otro

Comment: si, pero no lo renderiza en pantalla hasta que no sales del bucle

Comment: ¿has ejecutado el snippet que has puesto?  Yo veo que si se renderiza en pantalla (si entendemos **renderizar** por mostrar el resultado del innerHTML en cada ciclo... si te refieres a otra cosa explícate mejor pues no lo entiendo, lo siento)

Comment: no no, me refiero precisamente a eso. Al menos en mi ordenador (he probado firefox,chrome y brave) ejecuto el snippet y no aparece nada (cuadrado en blanco) hasta que pongo un número mayor a 10, que entonces, en la pantalla aparece: Bucle infinito compra papeleria 
Stock y el número de la variable. Pero si pongo un número distinto a 10, la pantalla continúa en blanco.

Comment: Mira, esto es lo que ocurre cuando lo hago yo: https://anonfiles.com/F9A2U4F4y2/yosiloveo_mp4  (es un mp4)... ¿a ti no te sucede lo mismo?

Comment: No... cuando lo hice en el trabajo (Windows 10), me salía así, pero en mi PC (Ubuntu y en Windows 10 tampoco) y probando con diferentes navegadores, la página detrás del prompt no se actualiza y normalmente sale en gris. Voy a probar a meterle un timer como indican abajo

Comment: Ok, como prefieras, pero es raro que ni ejecutándolo tal como te muestro en el video, es decir, desde esta propia pregunta, te salga distinto a mi. Pero en fin, el mundo está lleno de misterios :-)  Saludos!

Comment: Si quieres por curiosidad te grabo un vídeo, ya que te has tomado la molestia de hacerlo tu, pero vamos, ya te digo que sin el timer, se queda la pantalla en blanco hasta que sales del loop.

Comment: pues si, creo que me ayudaría a entenderlo mejor, y salir de mi asombro actual al ver que a tí se te ejecuta de otra forma distinta a la mostrada en el mismo, gracias por la molestia (es que soy muy curioso y creo que todo debe tener su explicación lógica)

Comment: https://anonfiles.com/36r5Y0Fcy9/Captura_del_escritorio_de_05-11-22_12_06_09_webm   ya me dirás si descubres el misterio

Comment: vaya mierda, jajaja... no sabia que salian esos hentais en esa web... nunca la hbia usado antes... vaya timo... asi pues, nunca llegastes a ver mi video?  ah, si, a la tercera... ya les vale

Comment: si, lo vi perfectamente. Quizá lo bloqueó brave.

Comment: pues tienes razon, no se ve... y veo que [en jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tn8v6kqo/) tampoco sale como a mi... seré un caso único en esta web, je

Comment: en Chrome me pasa lo que a ti...es decir, solo me funciona bien en Firefox... aquí hay una respuesta (en inglés) que te puede valer:  [Enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55310606/10382744||)   donde tambien usan funciones de temporizador para enviarlos a la cola (en ese caso el SetTimeout) además de async/await

Comment: muchas gracias por todo!

Comment: venga, un placer, suerte!  Saludos

Comment: Como curiosidad, creo que el misterio viene de la velocidad de procesamiento del navegador, por eso en el trabajo (ordenador antiguo) me funcionaba y aquí en casa no. Con el código ya funcionando y sin tocar nada, de repente ha dejado de funcionar y hacerlo como antes. He aumentado el timer a 100 (imperceptible) y ya funciona otra vez correctamente.

Comment: Pues no creo que sea eso, vamos, tampoco es que le estemos exigiendo una burrada al ordenador por hacer eso, ya sea nuevo o viejo, je.  Por cierto, deberías aceptar la respuesta que te haya servido para que la comunidad lo sepa y la pregunta no quede pendiente eternamente. En [este enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200) aprenderás ha hacerlo.  Recuerda también hacer el [tour] para aprender la dinámica completa del sitio (son 3 minutos de tutorial) y así aprender a colaborar mejor con este sitio, donde todos somos colaboradores :-)  Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

De seguro intentas hacer un bucle infinito como normalmente se haría:

```
while (true){...}
```

El problema que el navegador se queda ejecutando ese bucle y no redibuja la pagina. En javascript para hacer un bucle infinito y permitir que se cargue la pagina se usa la funcion setInterval(callback, time); que como parametro te pide una función y el tiempo de retraso por cada llamada.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <h2>Bucle infinito compra papelería</h2>
        <i><b>Nota:</b> Use clear para limpiar pantalla</i>
        <h3>Stock</h3>
        <p id="tablePrint"></p>
        <script>
            let compraManolo="";//lo iniciamos con una cadena vacía para que no nos salga undefined
            var idMainLoop=0;
            function mainLoop(){
            let output=document.getElementById("tablePrint");
                output.innerHTML += compraManolo+"<BR/>";
                compraManolo = prompt("Lápices?");

                if (compraManolo!="" && parseInt(compraManolo) > 10)//!="" Para evitar errores.
                   clearInterval(idMainLoop);//Termina nuestro bucle
                else if(compraManolo=="clear")
                   output.innerHTML=compraManolo="";//Nuevo comando que agregué, es para limpiar la tabla:)
            }
            idMainLoop=setInterval(mainLoop,1000);//1000 para que se ejecute por cada 1s
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

La función setInterval solo agrega una llamada a la cola de todo lo que se debe ejecutar en el navegador, permitiendo que se redibuje, etc... .

Si quieres detener el bucle puedes cambiar la última línea para almacenar el id de la iteración que estas usando:

```
var idMainLoop=setInterval(mainLoop,1000);//1000 == 1s
//Y detenemos usando clearInterval(idMainLoop);
```

### Enlaces externos:

- [setInterval() - in developer mozillia](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/setInterval)
- [clearInterval() - in developer mozillia](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/setInterval)

Comment: Retorna undefined, tendrías que validar que esto no suceda y el loop continúe.

Comment: Muchas gracias!! he probado la anterior y me funciona perfectamente. Supongo que así también lo haría. MUCHAS GRACIAS!

Answer (score 1):

Puedes ocupar [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) y quitar el while, reemplázalo por un función recursiva, la cual llamaremos nuevamente si la condición (compraManolo < 10) se cumple

De esta manera:

```js
let compraManolo=0;

function launchprompt(){
  setTimeout(function() {
     compraManolo = prompt("Lápices?");
     if(compraManolo!=undefined){
          document.getElementById('tablePrint').innerHTML += compraManolo +"<br />"; //agrega el número más abajo
          //document.getElementById('tablePrint').innerHTML = compraManolo; //reemplaza todo el contenido

        if (compraManolo < 10){
           launchprompt();
        }
     }

  },10);

}

launchprompt();
```

```html
<h2>Bucle infinito compra papeleria</h2>
<h3>Stock</h3>
<p id="tablePrint"></p>
```

Comment: Tampoco me fijé en que se sobre escribe la tabla por cada llamada a función.

Comment: Por fin! me funciona perfectamente y es una solución sencilla que puedo implementar sin cambiar casi el código. MUCHAS GRACIAS!!

Comment: @Javier Que bueno te haya servidor, recuerda marcar la respuesta como aceptada si así lo consideras.